# Как вывести таблицу из базы данных на сайт

Tags: python, django

Хочу вывести на сайт таблицу примерно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот файл **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import date
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid

class School_class(models.Model):
    school_class = models.CharField(max_length=10, help_text = 'Класс')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_class

class People(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text = 'Имя учащегося')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text = 'Фамилия учащегося')
    school_class = models.ForeignKey(School_class, help_text = 'Класс ученика', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

class State(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(help_text = 'Дата')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices = (
        ('+', '+'),
        ('-', '-')
        ))
    people = models.ForeignKey(People, help_text = 'Фамилия, имя учащегося', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.date, self.people.__str__())

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('date-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date']
```

Как вывести такие данные на сайт?

Comment: Предыдущий вопрос был ошибкой молодости, я его уже удалил -_-

Answer (score 1):

я сам нашел решение:
В моделях добавить в класс State метод Meta:

```
class Meta:
        ordering = ['people']
```

В шаблоне такая конструкция:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}<h1>State List</h1>

{% regroup object_list by people as list %}

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>People/Day</th>
      {% for i in list %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
          {% for d in i.list %}
            <th>{{d.date}}</th>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for i in list %}
      <tr scope = "row">
        <th>{{i.grouper}}</th>
        {% for d in i.list %}
          <th>{{d.status}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

- использую тег regroup
  Надеюсь, это поможет не только мне.
  Также фоточка итоговой таблицы (осталось ее только оформить красиво):
  [image]